# Detect Observable<any[]> if changes has been made

Tags: angular, observable

Is there any way how to detect/observe/watch/subscribe to `Observable<any[]>` if changes *(add, remove, update)* from the list has been made?

```
_objList: Observable<any[]>;


onDelete(i: index): void {
    this._objList.subscribe(list => {
        // delete from list logic...
    });
}

onAdd(data: any): void {
    this._objList.subscribe(list => {
        // add to list logic...
    });
}

OnListChanged(): void {
     // Do something if changes has been made to _objList.
}
```

Comment: You want a [Subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md). Basically it can broadcast out changes to any observers that are subscribed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BehaviorSubject` in RxJS. You can then subscribe or publish changes

```
_obList = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
```

Code sample here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zabmwe, refer to `app/app.component.ts` file.

More explanation on BehaviorSubject: https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components#toc-solution-3-use-rxjs-behaviorsubject

Comment: im still new to angular but a little demo will help a lot.